# Need a beginner lesson for Sessions Attribute in Alexa skill development

Tags: javascript, session-variables, alexa-skills-kit

Can someone please guide me to a very basic beginners tutorial for Sessions attribute in Alexa skill development. I want to understand how to be able to save data across handles and sessions.

I know very basic Javascript as of now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic tutorial [Cake Time](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/get-deeper/tutorials-code-samples/build-an-engaging-alexa-skill) covers setting/reading session data (across handlers) and setting persistent variables (across sessions) with a persistence adapter.

### Edit

[Part 2 of the SDK guided walk-through](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-guided-walkthrough-using-node-sdk/tree/master/part-2) is a bit old, but fairly beginner-friendly, still accurate (or so it seems from a quick look), and covers sessions and session attributes in more detail than Cake Time.

Handlers handle a single exchange. Sessions cover a set of exchanges in what might be seen as a single visit. So sessions store data across handlers. Persistence stores it across sessions.

If I come to your sit-up skill and say I did 23 sit-ups today. You might read my previous total from a persistence attribute and save the new value to a persistence attribute, because each day's use of your skill would be a session.

On the other hand if you ask my name on launch, then do various business, then say "Bye Greg" when I leave, you'd use a session attribute to remember my name between the first interaction and that goodbye interaction.

Comment: Yes, I have done Cakewalk. It covers the sessions attributes in a lession. It is step by step copy paste and doesnt explain much for a new comer like me. I am looking for guidance on each step and what all that means. Plus all the variations. What if I dont want to save data accross sessions only across various handles. I hope I am able to convey what I am trying to learn. Thankyou for answering back but Cake walk doesn't help me learn. I cannot replicate the process in my own code.

Comment: Try this one then. https://github.com/alexa/alexa-guided-walkthrough-using-node-sdk - It's a bit older, but the session handling hasn't changed. I'll update my answer to explain the concepts.